# Difference between Index error count and Index unindexed count

Tags: solr4, alfresco-webscripts

I am little bit confuse in solr report terminology can anyone help me.I am using `https://localhost:8443/solr4/admin/cores?action=REPORT&wt=xml` to generate the report in this report i am confuse in two tags one is **name="Index error count"** and another is **name="Index unindexed count**.Can anyone tell both are same or different?

Answer (score 0):

They are different. As the [documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/alfresco-reports.html) says:

> **Index error count**: Specifies the count of the error documents (ID starts with ERROR-) in the index. It is used to mark nodes that failed
>   to be indexed. If the value of this parameter is not zero, then there
>   is an issue with the index.
>
> **Index unindexed count**:Specifies the count of the unindexed documents (ID starts with UNINDEXED-) in the index. It is created for
>   nodes that have PROP_IS_INDEXED property set to false in the metadata.
>   This property is set to control indexing process, so it can be > 0.
>   For example, hidden and rendition nodes have this property set to
>   FALSE.